# CodeIgniter SMTP gives 'Read timeout (600s) waiting for data (CMD_DATA_END)'

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I set up the following code in CodeIgniter to send email with SMTP.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'send.one.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = '<MYEMAIL>';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '<MYPSSWD>';
$config['smtp_port'] = '587';
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('<MYEMAIL>', 'Test mailservice');
$this->email->to('mytestemail@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test - ROLO ');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
echo $this->email->send();
```

Connection with SMTP is no issue, I don't get anny errors. But the e-mail is not delivered to mytestemail@gmail.com and after a while I receive an error-message in the inbox of the from-address. Delivery Status Report:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; mailrelay3-4.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com
Received-from-MTA: smtp; <<MY IP OF APPLICATION>> (<<MY IP OF APPLICATION>>)
Original-Envelope-Id: 6ac5b195-f2f5-11e8-af49-d0431ea8bb03
Arrival-Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 10:07:31 +0000
Final-Recipient: rfc822; mytestemail@gmail.com
Action: delayed
Status: 5.4.7 (Message could not be delivered in the allotted time frame)
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 400 Network error: Read timeout (600s) waiting for 
data (CMD_DATA_END)
```

and the following (Undelivered Message Headers):

```
Received: from <<MY IP OF APPLICATION>> (unknown [<<MY IP OF APPLICATION>>])
by mailrelay3.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com (Halon) with ESMTPSA
id 6ac5b195-f2f5-11e8-af49-d0431ea8bb03;
Wed, 28 Nov 2018 10:07:30 +0000 (UTC)
Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 10:07:30 +0000
From: "test mailservice" <MYEMAIL>
Return-Path: <MYEMAIL>
To: mytestemail@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Email=20Test=20-=20ROLO=20?=
Reply-To: <MYEMAIL>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: <MYEMAIL>
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5bfe68e2a1fc6@MYEMAILDOMAIN>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5bfe68e2a1fd8"
```

Can somebody please help me? Tried to google but couldn't find similar issues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. After a lot of trial and error I found that adding the following line after initializing the email configuration solved my problem :

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Hope it helps !